# Why can't I multiply a hash value?

Tags: ruby

```
hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3}
new_hash = hash.each { |k, v| v.to_int * 5 }
new_hash
```

I want this output:

```
=> {"one"=>5, "two"=>10, "three"=>15}
```

But I get this:

```
=> {"one"=>1, "two"=>2, "three"=>3}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), `Hash#each` returns the *original* hash, which you then assign to `new_hash`.

Do this instead:

```
hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3}
new_hash = Hash[hash.map { |k, v| [k, v * 5] }]
new_hash # => {:one=>5, :two=>10, :three=>15}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but i'm looking for more of an explanation as to why my code attempt doesn't work.

Comment: @gwapEs9 Added explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`each` returns the original hash. You have to build a new one:

```
new_hash = hash.map { |k, v| [k, v * 5] }.to_h
#=> {:one=>5, :two=>10, :three=>15}
```

Or for Ruby < 2.1

```
new_hash = Hash[hash.map { |k, v| [k, v * 5] }]
#=> {:one=>5, :two=>10, :three=>15}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
hash = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3}
new_hash = hash.reduce({}) { |h, (k, v) | h[ k ] = v.to_i * 5 ; h }
# => {:one=>5, :two=>10, :three=>15}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a block is given, `each` method of `Hash` returns the original hash with no modification. See [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-each).